# How to display an image in a datagridview column header?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

At run-time, I am adding a `DataGridView` to a windows form. The final column is a `DataGridViewImageColumn`:

```
Dim InfoIconColumn As New DataGridViewImageColumn
MyDataGridView.Columns.Insert(MyDataGridView.Columns.Count, InfoIconColumn)
```

Adding the following code will get my Information Icon (bitmap) to display in each of the column cells but NOT the column header:

```
Dim InfoIcon As New Bitmap("C:\MyPath\InfoIcon.bmp")
InfoIconColumn.Image = InfoIcon
```

Also, it is worth noting that the image displays 'perfectly' in the cells i.e. it is sized correctly to fit the cell.

However, I cannot find a way to add the same image to the column header cell. After some googling I used the following code which placed the image in the header cell but left me with two problems:

1. The image did not 'auto-size' to the column headercell in the same way it did when added to the column cells. The image was slightly larger and blurred.
2. By using the `_CellPainting` event slowed down performance i.e. when hovering over the `DataGridView` to highlight the selected row the highlighting lagged behind where my mouse was placed.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub MyDataGridView_CellPainting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles MyDataGridView.CellPainting
   Dim InfoIcon As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\MyPath\InfoIcon.bmp")
   If e.RowIndex = -1 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = MyDataGridView.Columns.Count - 1 Then
       e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All And Not   DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground)
       e.Graphics.DrawImage(InfoIcon, e.CellBounds)
       e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Does anybody know of a way to solve my problem and get a nicely sized, sharp image into a `DataGridViewImageColumn` headercell at run-time?

Answer (score 18):

One way you can do this is to use the `CellsPainting` event to draw the
bitmap for a particular header cell. Here is code that does this
assuming the bitmap is in an `imagelist`.

```
//this.images is an ImageList with your bitmaps
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex == -1)
    {
        e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);

        Point pt = e.CellBounds.Location;  // where you want the bitmap in the cell

        int offset = (e.CellBounds.Width - this.images.ImageSize.Width) / 2;
        pt.X += offset;
        pt.Y += 1;
        this.images.Draw(e.Graphics, pt, 0);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the event you don't store the Image in an ImageList, modifying the 2nd last LOC to; e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, pt); also works.

Comment: It works but how can I place the image by text's side with some padding?

Answer (score 4):

I needed a bit more complex thing - adding image in front of text in *some* column headers with respect to column alignment.

You need to implement your own [`System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumnheadercell(v=vs.110).aspx) and replace `ColumnHeaderCell`:

```
// Create header and set up image
YourDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell headerCell = new YourDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell();
headerCell.Image = something;

// Create column
DataGridViewColumn yourColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(); 
// ...
yourColumn.ColumnHeaderCell = new headerCell;
```

Now the funny part (implementation of your column header):

```
class YourDataGridViewColumnHeaderCell : System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell
{
    // Set up image as you want
    System.Drawing.Image Image { get; set; }
}
```

Now we want to add [`Paint()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumnheadercell.paint(v=vs.110).aspx) method. The only tricky part is working with [`System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewPaintParts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159092(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
protected override void Paint( Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates dataGridViewElementState,
    object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
    DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts )
{
    // Outside header or without an image, use default painting
    if ((rowIndex != -1) || (Image == null)) {
        base.Paint( graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, dataGridViewElementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts );
        return;
    }

    // Borders, background, focus selection can remain the same
    // But Foreground will have different image
    base.Paint( graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, dataGridViewElementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle,
        advancedBorderStyle, paintParts & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground );

    // Repainting of content background (that's where we want to place our image)
    if ((paintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentBackground) != DataGridViewPaintParts.None) {
        // +4 is hardcoded margin 
        Point bounds = new Point( cellBounds.X + 4, cellBounds.Y );

        // Handle vertical alignment correctly
        switch (cellStyle.Alignment) {
            // Top
            case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopLeft:
            case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter:
            case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopRight:
                // Already set
                break;

            // Middle
            case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft:
            case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter:
            case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight:
                bounds.Y = cellBounds.Y + (cellBounds.Height - Image.Height) / 2;
                break;

            // Bottom
            case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomLeft:
            case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter:
            case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight:
                bounds.Y = cellBounds.Y + (cellBounds.Height - Image.Height);
                break;

        }
        graphics.DrawImage( Image, bounds );
    }

    // Foreground should be shifted by left image margin + image.width + right 
    // image margin and of course target spot should be a bit smaller
    if ((paintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground) != DataGridViewPaintParts.None) {
        Rectangle newCellBounds = new Rectangle( cellBounds.X + 4 + Image.Width + 4, cellBounds.Y, cellBounds.Width - Image.Width - 8, cellBounds.Height );
        base.Paint( graphics, clipBounds, newCellBounds, rowIndex, dataGridViewElementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle,
            advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground );
    }

}
```

If you want to use [`AutoSizeColumnsMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizecolumnsmode(v=vs.110).aspx) set to [`DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeaders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnsmode(v=vs.110).aspx) (so you would autofit image **and** text) you need to override [`DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell.GetPreferredSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumnheadercell.getpreferredsize(v=vs.110).aspx). I did this by using base implementation and adding `Image.Width + Padding` to it.

```
protected override Size GetPreferredSize( Graphics graphics, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, int rowIndex,Size constraintSize )
{
    // Load up original image
    Size original = base.GetPreferredSize( graphics, cellStyle, rowIndex, constraintSize );

    // Ensure the image is set and that we are working on header
    if ((rowIndex != -1) || (Image == null)) {
        return original;
    }

    // -1 is reserved value
    if (original.Width < 0) {
        return original;
    }
    return new Size( original.Width + Image.Width + 4, original.Height );
}
```

***NOTE***: I've spent several hours digging in [.NET sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewMethods.cs#1713) until I figured this out. Hopefully you won't have to.

Comment: Can we add panel control just above the `datagridview column headers` ?

Comment: @KhurramAli I've never tested/tried that... I think it should be possible... If you get to test it, please let me know whether it worked.

Comment: @Vyktor DataGridViewColumn  has no such property ColumnHeaderCell. Can you clarify?

Comment: @user3700562 according to [`DataGridViewColumn` the `HeaderCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.headercell\(v=vs.110\).aspx) is *Available since 2.0*. But it also notes that it's `[BrowsableAttribute(false)]` so you are **NOT** able to see it in designer (but have to change it programmatically).

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellPainting(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellPainting
        If e.RowIndex > -1 Then

            If e.ColumnIndex = -1 Then
                e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.Focus And Not DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground)
                DataGridView1.RowHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Single
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(IconImg, e.CellBounds)
                e.Handled = True
                'DataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 100
                'DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight = 25
            End If

        End If
```

Comment: You should explain what you are doing. I was lucky that I tried your code since e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.Focus And Not DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground) was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellPainting(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) _
            Handles DataGridView1.CellPainting
        If e.RowIndex = -1 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 Then
            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All And Not DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground)
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(IconImg, e.CellBounds)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

if you have read full article for doing this check This link:

http://www.authorcode.com/add-image-on-datagridview-column-header-in-vb-net/