# adding an image to the header of a .net datagridview

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I just need a way to insert an image into the header of a vb.net data grid view. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196400/how-to-display-an-image-in-a-datagridview-column-header) to a similar SO question.

or you might find your answer here:

[Adding Image to the DataGridView editing column](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/63ec6688-b1da-462b-accc-14356e74947a/)

[How To Insert Image To DataGridView Column Header](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/20a17f95-0089-4148-b3b0-3abef1b0d735)

Comment: Second link (Adding image...) leads to "This item has been deleted."