# Can I display number of row on RowHeaders in the DataGridView?

Tags: c#

my datagridview is right to left.

when i use this code , numbers show on last column.

when datagridview is left to right this code is correct.

I want to display number of row and image on all RowHeader of DataGridView;

```
private void DataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{ 
    using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(DataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor)) 
    { 
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.RowIndex.ToString(), e.InheritedRowStyle.Font, b, e.RowBounds.Location.X + 20, e.RowBounds.Location.Y + 4); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display Text in grid view header like following.

```
private void dataGridView_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView gridView = sender as DataGridView;

    if (gridview !=null)
    {
        gridView.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value = string.format("Total Number of Rows:  {0}",gridview .Rows.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have not event RowDataBound for DataGridView.

Comment: Use Row Validated event

Comment: and you can add header image like following link -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196400/how-to-display-an-image-in-a-datagridview-column-header

Comment: RowValidated is not good event for this work. user can not see before click on row and i emphasize my code work while datagridview is left to right when datagridview is right to left code dose not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DataGridView.RowCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowcount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property.

In this example, this property is used to track the number of entries in a DataGridView