# Change header in datagridview

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview with two columns. I want only the header of the first column stand with bold font and color in red. The second column will not be changed. How do?

Comment: This question might help you.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196400/how-to-display-an-image-in-a-datagridview-column-header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read this: [DataGridViewCell.Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.style(v=vs.110).aspx) property

And this tutorial: [How to: Set Font and Color Styles in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z2akwyy7(v=vs.100).aspx)